# How far above the initial stack pointer can I access without faulting?

Tags: x86, stack, x86-64, callstack

In this GAS code:

```
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%ld\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    endbr64 
    pushq   %rbp    
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  
    subq    $16, %rsp   
    #HOW FAR CAN I GO FROM BASE POINTER?
    movq    10000(%rbp), %rax   
    movq    %rax, %rsi  
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    
    movl    $0, %eax    
    call    printf@PLT  
    movl    $0, %eax    
    leave   
    ret
```

I am addressing `10000(%rbp)`,which sometimes terminated, sometimes give a value at that address. So the question is, how far from the base pointer in the stack I can address, in other words, how big stack has kernel allocate for my process? Is it a constant? It is variable? Where can I find out?

Comment: It obviously depends on the OS, but on Linux argv[] (and the pointed-to args) and then the environment variables will be above RSP on entry to `_start` (the process entry point), and main is only a bit farther down the stack from there.  (A few CRT startup calls use some stack space.)  Anyway, if this is GNU/Linux, tag your question with [tag:linux].  I think there's some randomization relative to a page boundary as well.

Comment: If you're on Linux, could you try this? Run your program  under gdb, type `set disable-randomization off`, then `b main`, then `run`.  When the program stops, run `info proc map` and look at the second number on the `[stack]` line. Then run `print <that number> - (unsigned long long)$rsp`. Try this a few times and show us the results.

Comment: (Possibly transparent-hugepages could be relevant as well, although the initial stack mapping is probably small enough that the kernel wouldn't consider making it part of a 2M hugepage)